# R Markdown: custom syntax highlighting style

Tags: r, r-markdown, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to find the theme and syntax highlighting style used in [R for data science book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html) but apparently, they don't exist in the `knitr` library. If they are indeed custom styles, where can I find them and how can I apply them to my R markdown document?

Comment: You can find information about the theme used and the syntax highlighting in the book’s source code: https://github.com/hadley/r4ds/blob/first-ed/_output.yaml (note that the repository also contains the book’s second edition; I linked you to the first edition style since that is what you were asking about).

Comment: Thank you. could you please point me to a source where it teaches how to replicate those styles in my own documents?